# Flutter BottomNavigationBar - Multi-line for label?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have attached below an image of `BottomNavigationBarItem`. As you can see here, it's showing ellipsis for long text. I want to show this label in two lines. How can I achieve this? Any idea?

*Note:* There is a property named `unselectedLabelStyle` for `BottomNavigationBar`. I tried to use that also.

[image]

```dart
// ...
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: selectedIndex!,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: onItemSelected,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: _bottomNavIcon(
            Icons.home,
            color: ColorsX.lightGrey),
          activeIcon: _bottomNavIcon(Icons.home_filled),
          label: "Self Assessment"
        )
      ]
    );
  }
// ...
```

Comment: please add your source code

Comment: @JahidulIslam added.

Comment: you may need to customize the bottom navigation bar and use it according to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `\n` in your label

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: selectedIndex!,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: onItemSelected,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: _bottomNavIcon(
            Icons.home,
            color: ColorsX.lightGrey),
          activeIcon: _bottomNavIcon(Icons.home_filled),
          label: 'I am \n multi \n line'
        )
      ]
    );
  }
```

Comment: Apparently, it works. But it breaks the alignment of the text. Lebel becomes left aligned by this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using `TextOverflow.visible`

```
BottomNavigationBar(
  selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(
     overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
  ),
  unselectedLabelStyle: St.noto_regular_11.copyWith(
     overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
  ),
```